# How can I control when my css transitions happen and when they don't?

Tags: css-transitions

I'm trying to show a form's `submit` and `reset` buttons only once the user has made changes to the form. My original method is simple: add a `hidden` class to the buttons on page load and remove it when the form is modified. This works well enough. But when I add a transition in the mix, the transition takes place when I originally add the `hidden` class on page load, which is unwanted.

Here is the relevant code ([or see it live on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shawn/KVSTg/)):

**html**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    &.hidden {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

**javascript (using JQuery 1.9.1)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var buttons = $('input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"]').addClass('hidden');
    $('form').on(
        'change input',
        ':input',
        function () {
            buttons.removeClass('hidden');
        }
    ).on(
        'reset',
        function () {
            buttons.addClass('hidden');
        }
    );
});
```

How can I enable the transition only after the `hidden` class has been added the first time?

Comment: It would probably be simpler to start out hidden then add a show class on change.

Comment: @dc5 I want it to be usable in browsers where javascript is turned off. That's why I add the hidden class with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the transition to its own class as well.  On page load, add the hidden class, then, after a timeout, add the transition class.

The timeout, in this case, is to let the browser apply/render the opacity: 0 style of the hidden class immediately, without any transition timing. Once that has occurred, adding the transition class causes any further changes to use the transition timing when applicable.

something like ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KVSTg/2/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var buttons = $('input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"]').addClass('hidden');

    window.setTimeout(function() { buttons.addClass('txclasshere'); }, 0);
    $('form').on(
        'change input',
        ':input',
        function () {
            buttons.removeClass('hidden');
        }
    ).on(
        'reset',
        function () {
            buttons.addClass('hidden');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Could you add a note explaining why `setTimeout` is necessary here? I suppose that breaking the javascript execution gives the browser a chance of redrawing the page with the `hidden` class before the next class is added; Correct?